# Create function/object in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

How I can create a thing which is both *function* and *object* at a same time?
Suppose its name is `obj`.
In the following context it is a object:

```
obj.key1 = "abc";
obj.key2 = "xyz";
```

And in another context it is a function like this:

```
var test = obj("abc");
```

How I can create this object in JavaScript?

Comment: This is just how functions are. Functions ARE objects. so if you do `function test(param) { alert(param); }`, you could do `test.prop = 'testProp'`

Comment: See a tutorial like http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-basics-of-object-oriented-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function obj( param ){
    var that = this;

    that.key1 = "default";
    that.key2 = "default";

    that.someMethod = function(){
        return param;
    };

    that.showMessage = function(){
        alert( param );
    };

    return that;
}
```

and then:

```
var test = obj("hi there");
test.key1 = "abc";
test.key2 = "xyz";
test.showMessage();
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Xnye5/

or

```
obj("hi there again").showMessage();
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Xnye5/1

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you tell me how i can implement `obj("hi there").showMessage()` / firebug give me error : **obj is not a function**

Comment: no no, i want to use this method with this convention: `obj("hi there").showMessage()`

Comment: I want to use my object like `jQuery` object

Comment: @ABFORCE you can't use it this way because obj("hi there") will return  what this function return (or undefined in case of it doesnt return anything) and that returned value dont have `.showMessage()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
 function obj( param ) {
     console.log( param );
 }

 obj.prototype.key1 = "abc";
 obj.prototype.key2 = "xyz"; 

 var test = new obj( "abc" );
 console.log( test.key1 );
 console.log( test.key2 );
```

Key `new` needed to save function context. You can use `return this` in function to avoid this.

Or using `this` instead of prototype:

```
 function obj( param ) {
     console.log( param );
     this.key1 = "abc";
     this.key2 = "xyz";
 }
```

Comment: Or `var obj = function(param) {....}`, just so one knows there are options, and in case he needs more than 1 of them.